# About the Soul Stone

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, avengers-infinity-war

Does anyone know who else is in the soul stone? And if anyone has used its power before?

> What happens to Red Skull after the soul stone was taken from Vormir?

Comment: What do you mean *in* the soul stone?

Comment: @Möoz as in what other souls are in it? Like gamora was in the soul stone?

Comment: @ThusalHettiarachchi Why do you think Gamora was inside the soul stone?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist at the end of infinity war after thanos snaps his fingers he goes in to the soul world and talks with Gamora, I think that’s the soul world where the souls absorbed by the soul stone go to

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The Russo brothers have confirmed that’s it’s the soul world within the soul stone

Comment: There are 3 different questions here. This is going to be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is based on the movie and MCU (Marvel Cinematic Universe) only.

I believe that at the end of the movie:

> Thanos is shown talking to Gamora. I don't believe he goes into the Soul Stone itself, but the Soul Stone teleports him to where the Gamora's soul is. (Purely my guess.)

As for the Soul Stone itself, at the end of the first "Captain America" movie:

> Red Skull was teleported to a hitherto unknown place by the Tesseract.

We now know from "Infinity War" that:

> He was actually teleported to the planet where the Soul Stone was. Based on his disembodied presence and his explanation that he is there to guide others to the stone, to attain what he could not himself, he understood how to obtain the Soul Stone, but perished while doing so.

As for how that happened, the movie doesn't really go into detail, so that's anyone's guess. Here's mine (not based on the movie):

> He jumped off the cliff, but died in the attempt, which is how he understood what it took to get the Soul Stone. But being dead himself, he wasn't able to obtain the Soul Stone for himself and just drifted about as a Soul, guiding others to this Infinity Gem.

I personally thought it was a nice touch in how they introduced the Soul Stone in "Infinity War" and in none of the movies preceding it, and somehow tied it to Red Skull and the ending of "Captain America" as well.

Comment: "I personally thought it was a nice touch" - agree to disagree.  I found that both confusing and felt like they were trying too hard.

Comment: Agree to disagree :) I had thought (like others online) that it would have been introduced in Black Panther, and again, it's purely my personal opinion that it thought it was a nice touch that they added it in Infinity War, and how Gamora was the only one to know about it and that entire story arc; I thought it added depth to the storyline. Again, IMHO. :)

Comment: Oh, that stuff was fine. I was speaking specifically of the Red Skull tie in.

Comment: My understanding of Red Skull's comment is that he couldn't get the Soul Stone since there was nothing he really loved and could sacrifice.

Comment: @Taladris - However Red Skull was also (punished or tasked) with the burden of helping any who came to the stone; including knowing details of the individuals themselves. I don't see him as just stranded where the stone was without the ability to get it given he not only knew who Thanos and Gamora were, but that he also ?knew? their feelings and thus the actions Thanos would take. He seems to have been a little omnipotent for someone just stranded there.

Comment: @Odin1806: you are right. There are many things unclear to me with Red Skull scene.